# Browser not calling new Ajax Request on Page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have setup properties in my Ajax Request not to store cache. I have also added query string as a parameter in the URL to call new Ajax request. But whenever i refresh the page i see old content on the page. I always have to hard refresh a page to see the updated content. 
The request headers are getting passed to the browser correctly which i have set in the properties of ajax. But why do i always have to hard refresh to get the updated content. How can i load the new content on just a page refresh. I have pasted my Ajax below

AJAX Methods to set the properties

```
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        if (options.type == 'POST') {
            options.url +=  '?' + Date.now();
        }
    });

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
        headers: {
        'Cache-Control':'max-age=0, public'
        },
    });
```

My JQuery

```
 $.ajax({
                            url: "/Configuration/TestPlan/GetUserList",
                            type: 'POST',
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            // async :false,
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                //call pageloader 
                                showImageLoader();
                            },
                            data:jsonString,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
```

Comment: if you look in the dev tools, network tab - do you: 1. See the cachebuster at the end of your request and is it different every time (the numbers generated by Date.now())?  2.  The data that is being requested - if you preview the data being returned (in the network tab) does it look right?)

Comment: Hi @RacilHilan. there is a lot of code and logic written in my success method. I cant paste everything here

Comment: @Kyle: Yes the number changes every time i refresh the page. But whenever i comment out the date.now and refresh the page, the network tab still show the date.now number appended after the method name. Is it of cache or i am misunderstanding here and my data is not being returned from cache?

Comment: @RacilHilan I suppose you didnt understand the question. the question is not of the data that i am returning incorrect. The question is of cache, which the AJAX has predefined properties. i want to verify whether my approach for cache is correct or not.

Comment: OK, setting the `cache` property to `false` is good. You don't need to do it multiple times, inside `$.ajax` it will only affect that call, while inside `$.ajaxSetup` it will affect all calls on that page. That's all there to it. If it is really only about caching, then your problem is not in the code you posted. Try to see which point is not respecting the cashing request.

Answer (score 0):

From [jquery - ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - "If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests" -

So I don't think the cache option is doing what you think.  Since it's a POST the only thing that will affect the cache-busting is that little snippet you have:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        if (options.type == 'POST') {
            options.url +=  '?' + Date.now();
        }
    });
```

Every time it makes a request - that page is actually being cached. It just does a new Date.now() - then that url is cahced until you do a new Date.now().

So when you comment it out - the last page/data called for is cached and now you've commented out the only thing updating the cachebuster.

Perhaps just apply the cache busting directly to the raw call:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/Configuration/TestPlan/GetUserList?" + Date.now(),
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    // async :false,
    beforeSend: function () {
    //call pageloader 
        showImageLoader();
    },
    data:jsonString,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
```

Comment: All of that is uncalled for. You quoted the jQuery docs at the beginning of your answer and that's great, but why did you stop there? Complete the sentence: *The parameter is not needed for other types of requests*. `POST` requests must not be cached by any point, so the OP needs to investigate which point is faulty. As for what you called "cache busting" (I like the name, is that official?), it is better to assign it to a parameter just like jQuery does `'?_=' + Date.now()`. But again, it is unnecessary because jQuery is already doing that when required.

Comment: yeah, 'cache busting' is pretty official just give it the ol' google and you'll see what I mean :)

Comment: Hi @Kyle What i am doing is adding a unique identifier to the url by giving a new DateTime. But even if i comment out the DateTime. The network tab still shows the parameter in the URL until i hard refresh it.